# How to join two tables in action result and bind with kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

Hi i am binding kendo grid with two tables below is the sequence i used for that.

```html
 public class EFEmployeeRepositary : IEmployeeRepositary
    {
        private EFDBContext context;
        public EFEmployeeRepositary()
        {
            this.context = new EFDBContext();
        }

        public IQueryable<Entities.Employee> Employees
        {
            get
            {
                return context.Employees;
            }
        }
        public IQueryable<Entities.GetEmployeeDetails> GetEmployeesDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return context.GetEmployeesDetails;
            }
        }
}
```

```html
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Table1", Schema = "dbo")]    
    public class Employee
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
       
        public int Staff_Seq_Number { get; set; }
        public string Staff_Number { get; set; }
        public string Full_Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOJ { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public string Nationality_Code { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Marital_Status_Code { get; set; }
        public string Gender_Code { get; set; }
    }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Table2", Schema = "dbo")]    
    public class GetEmployeeDetails
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public int Staff_Seq_Number { get; set; }
        public int Matrix_ID { get; set; }
        public int Grade_ID { get; set; }
        public int Position_ID { get; set; }

    }
public class MergeTables
    {
        public Employee employees { get; set; }
        public GetEmployeeDetails GetEmployeesDetails { get; set; }
      
    }
```

This is my Interface EmployeeRepository class where i added both class

```html
 public interface IEmployeeRepositary
    {
        IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get; }
        IQueryable<GetEmployeeDetails> GetEmployeesDetails { get; }
IQueryable<MergeTables> GetMergeTables { get; }
}
```

This is my dbcontext class

```html
 public DbSet<Employee> Employees
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DbSet<EmployeeHistory> EmployeesHistory
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public DbSet<MergeTables> GetMergeTables
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
```

This is my controller where called this interface repository

```html
 private IEmployeeRepositary employeeRepositary;
       
       
        public DashboardController(IEmployeeRepositary pEmployeeRepositary)
        {
            this.employeeRepositary = pEmployeeRepositary;
           
        }
```

and in same controller i have this actionresult function

```html
 public ActionResult Employee_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {

          
            var p = (from emp in this.employeeRepositary.Employees
                     join empdetails in this.employeeRepositary.GetEmployeesDetails on emp.Staff_Seq_Number equals empdetails.Staff_Seq_Number
                    
                     select new MergeTables()
                     {

                     });
            return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
              
        }
```

1st Issue: when i am running this i am getting error that "one or more validation errors were detected during model generation has no key defined" which new class MergeTables i created there i am getting issue.

2nd Issue: if i remove mergetables from Repository and and DBContext class this query is working fine but no data is showing in kendo grid

i have shown here two models but more than two models i used and binding in Action result.

Below is the kendo grid code:

```html
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GEMS.Domain.Entities.MergeTables>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Staff_Number).Title("EmployeeId");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Full_Name).Title("Name");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Age).Title("Age");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Email_Address).Title("EmailId");
            columns.Bound(p => p.GetHierarchyTemp.Department).Title("Department");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.DOB).Title("Date of birth");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.DOJ).Title("Date of joining");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Marital_Status_Code).Title("Marital Status");
            columns.Bound(p => p.employees.Nationality_Code).Title("Nationality Code");

        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .ColumnMenu()
        .Filterable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable
            .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
            .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
        .Navigatable()
        .AllowCopy(true)
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(10))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:380px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Employee_Read", "Dashboard"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
        )
```

can any one help me about these two issues how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

```html
use the word [Key] above your model items. 

example:

class telefoon{

[Key]
Int id {get:set}
int number{get:set}
}

like this
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.